# Changing a horizontal bar chart to a vertical one

Tags: c#, charts, bar-chart

I'm using the'*System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting*' library for my chart and I was wondering if anyone figured out how to switch the axes to display the chart vertically

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Changed

```
myChart.Series["mySeries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
```

to

```
myChart.Series["mySeries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
```