# C# WindowsForms - How to rotate Chart Graph/Axis

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

My question is: How can I change the normal graph(left one) to the graph I want(right one)? I cant find it anywhere.

[image]

[image]

I want the full yellow square to be 1,1. **How can I see the BackImage size so I can make the background image compatible? I only want the graph size not the actual chart.**

Comment: There is nothing in this question that helps us help you. Such as are you using a library. Any code example etc.

Comment: I edited..........

Comment: Im not using any library. Just C# WindowsForms chart.

Comment: It got a little worse.. how are you making your chart currently??

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with secondary and primary axis?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374862/changing-a-horizontal-bar-chart-to-a-vertical-one

Comment: I just want the X axis on the top and the y axis going down. I think it's pretty obvious on the first image.

Comment: No. It's not that.

Comment: Do you know the answer to the bolt question i made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to reverse the Y-Axis

---

```
yourChart.Chartareas[0].AxisY.IsReversed = true;
```

- Your other question is just as simple: You can set an `BackImage` for your `ChartArea` and if you set the `BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Scaled` it will always nicely fill the `ChartArea` even when you resize the chart or when the `Labels` or the `Legend` grows or shrinks..

Comment: perfect. Do you also know the answer to my 2nd question? I wanted to align each square to a position. Like full yellow square to 1,1 ,etc...

Comment: For this I would need to know much more about how the chart is created. Please add to your question!

Comment: Maybe if I know the graph area I can make a equal size image on photoshop so I can represent what I want.

Comment: Is there a way I can talk to you? Like a chat or something? thx

Comment: Can't say I quite understand; you can try but, yes maybe this would help? You can set the BackgroundImage and its Alignment.. - Um no, not until you gain a little more reps..

Comment: The problem is that the image is not the size of the actual graph so the squares are not on the right x,y position

Comment: If I make an image with the exact size of the graph maybe I can do it. Without neededing to use "scaled".

Comment: That's why I wanted to know how can I get the actual graph width and height. Not the chart.

Comment: @MaurícioVilarinho your question is answered with a correct answer. Avoid chatting in the comment section. If you run into another issue (hopefully **after trying yourself first**). You can make a new question regarding the problem/issue you are having.

Comment: Yes; you need to set the BachgroundImageLayout to stretch. You can get the pixels from chart.ClientSize but the actual [inner plotposition rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040569/convert-chart-coords-to-pixels/38461385?s=1|0.1564#38461385) is smaller

Comment: Yes, you must not take it directly as it is set to Auto (0,0) and also is in percantages!!. Use the function(s) found in the link instead!! And call them __after__ the chart is done with its layout!  - But I'm not sure the resizing will stay in synch.. If it doesn't you would have to create an adapted image on the fly. Well worth of another question if your attempts fail. Do try first!!

Comment: After coding it I found that you can simply set an image for each Chartarea :-) See my update!